# Convergence of Evolutionary Algorithms

Tags: optimization, convergence

When it comes to Evolutionary Algorithms (e.g. Genetic Algorithm), I have often heard people make the following broad statement: "**Evolutionary Algorithms Do Not Converge**."

I was curious about know how true this statement is, or does it come with any caveats. For instance, I was interested in knowing if perhaps there might be some conditions in which Evolutionary Algorithms have been known to converge. Reading online, I found the two following links to recent research papers on this topic:

1. [Average Convergence Rate of Evolutionary Algorithms in Continuous Optimization](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.11672.pdf), Chen et al., 2021

> It is proven that the ACR is linear for evolutionary programming using positive landscape-adaptive mutation, but sublinear for that using landscape-invariant or zero landscape-adaptive mutation.

2. [Sufficient Conditions for Global Convergence of Differential Evolution Algorithm](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/jam/2013/193196/), Hu et al., 2013

> Sufficient condition and a corollary for the convergence of DE (Differential Evolution - a type of Evolutionary Algorithm) to the global optima are derived by using the infinite product.

All this brings me to my question: There clearly seems to be some research and evidence suggesting that Evolutionary Algorithms can "sometimes" converge for some conditions - yet, we are constantly (informally) reminded that the "Evolutionary Algorithms Do Not Converge"; or in the instances where Evolutionary Algorithms do perform well, it's quickly said that "its very likely a Non-Evolutionary Algorithm could have performed equally well".

In the end, I am not sure what to believe, my knowledge of mathematics is insufficient to fully understand the literature and thoroughly be able to comment on this - **Do we have any mathematical knowledge suggesting that in certain cases (e.g. certain types of Loss Functions) Evolutionary Algorithms have a "strong ability" to converge?** Or do we only have the famous Schema Theorem - all we can be sure of, is that Evolutionary Algorithms are probabilistically guaranteed to provide better results relative to previous iterations, but no guarantee on convergence.

Can someone please comment on this?

Comment: You should specify (i) what problems you are considering evolutionary algorithms for, for example finding the minimum of a function $f(\mathbf x)$ or for sampling from a probability distribution, and (ii) what "convergence" is actually supposed to mean.

Comment: The convergence could also depend strongly on the system being used. If the system has a high crossover rate and low mutation rate it would almost certainly converge. If a system has a high mutation rate and doesn't allow for duplicate individuals to exist in a population it could almost be guaranteed that the population does not converge.